# Flutter 2 dimensional List/Array as Int/Object(class)

Tags: flutter

I need a multidimensional array/list (2 and/or 3 dimensions) which must contains different objects.
This is what I found:

```
  List recipes = List.generate(
      999,
      (_) => List<Ingredient>.filled(
          9,
          Ingredient(
              name: '', carboidrates: 0, proteins: 0, lipids: 0, fibers: 0),
          growable: true));
```

My needs is to have recipes[index/int][index/Ingredient].somethingoftheIngredientClass

As for example, if I create a single List:

```
List<Ingredient> recipe = <Ingredient>[];
```

I can access the class as

```
recipe[0].carboidrates
```

Not the same for my 2 dimensional list:

```
recipes[0][0].doesnotshowCarboidrates
```

Comment: maybe using `Map` is the right choice for your case.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I'll check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list or multi-dimensional lists can only have a single type. Looking at your sample code, it looks like you're trying to associate ingredients and properties of a given recipe to a recipe using a multi-dimensional list.

A better approach would be to use classes. Classes will give you a more structured design and a little more flexibility. For example, the code below overrides the equality operator (`==`) and `hashCode` to be able to compare recipes and find a given recipe in a list.

```dart
class Recipe {
  final String name;
  final List<Ingredient> ingredients;
  final List<Instruction> instructions;

  Recipe({
    required this.name,
    required this.ingredients,
    required this.instructions,
  });

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) || other is Recipe && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && name == other.name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode ^ ingredients.hashCode ^ instructions.hashCode;
}

class Ingredient {
  final String name;
  final String description;

  Ingredient({
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
  });
}

class Instruction {
  final String description;
  final String? tip;

  Instruction({
    required this.description,
    this.tip,
  });
}

final recipes = [
  Recipe(
    name: 'Cheese pizza',
    ingredients: [
      Ingredient(name: 'Dough', description: 'Normal yeast based pizza dough'),
      Ingredient(name: 'Tomato Sauce', description: 'Freshly blended organic tomatoes'),
      Ingredient(name: 'Mozzarella Cheese', description: 'Cheesy cheesiness from mount cheese'),
    ],
    instructions: [
      Instruction(description: 'Preheat oven to 400 degrees Fahrenheit'),
      Instruction(description: 'While oven is preheating spread dough evenly in a circle over an oiled pan'),
      Instruction(description: 'Spread sauce evenly over dough leaving enough room for the crust'),
      Instruction(description: 'Cover the sauce with the Mozzarella cheese'),
      Instruction(
        description: 'Roll the edge of the dough to form the crust',
        tip: 'Optionally add cheese within the dough for stuffed crust!',
      ),
      Instruction(description: 'Bake the pizza in the over until golden brown'),
      Instruction(
        description: 'Remove the pizza from the oven and let cool',
        tip: 'Some people like to let the pizza cool before cutting',
      ),
    ],
  ),
];

/// Find the index of a recipe. This uses the equality and hashcode overrides of the recipe class.
int getRecipeIndex(Recipe recipe) => recipes.indexOf(recipe);

/// Find all of the recipes containing the [query] in their name (case-insensitive).
List<Recipe> getRecipeByName(String query) {
  return recipes.where((element) => element.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())).toList();
}

/// Get the ingredients of a recipe.
final recipeIngredients = recipes[0].ingredients;

/// Get the instructions of a recipe.
final recipeInstructions = recipes[0].instructions;

/// Get a list of all of the tips for a recipe.
final recipeTips = recipes[0].instructions.map((e) => e.tip).whereType<String>();
```

If for whatever reason you wanted to associate a recipe with a list of recipes (e.g. similar recipes) I would use a `map` of `Recipe` to `List<Recipe>`.

```dart
final pizza = recipes[0];

/// How to associate a recipe with similar recipes using a map of `Recipe` to `List<Recipe>`
final similarRecipesMap = { pizza: [recipes[1], recipes[2]]};

final similarRecipesToPizza = similarRecipesMap[pizza];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: My App is a Calories/Counter. I'm trying to maximize code performance and compact. I also need list to populate some ListView Builders. The app has 3 recipe 5 times per day. Really complex to explain but I will certainly need 3 dimensional list.
As for example I use an AlertDialog to create a new ingredient and I would like to use a Tab Index to automatic insert in the correct list (to iterate too). In my mind 3d list it's perfect, probably because I don't know very well maps. Thanks for your great works that I will absolutely study.

Comment: As to explain more, the app will have two types of tabs (5 tabs for: breakfast, snack, lunch, snack, dinner), (3 tabs for 3 recipes for each first tabs).
By using 3d list I can always know where to put data (and where to read) and iterate too (for builders). One piece of code can now move (write/read) on the whole app.

Comment: That's great. Thank you for the explanation and good luck on your app! :)

Comment: Finally, Map object is what I looking for... Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just found a programming 'bug'.

I tried to replicate my exactly code:

```
  List recipes = List.generate(
      999,
      (_) => List<Ingredient>.filled(
          9,
          Ingredient(
              name: 'Cheesecake',
              carboidrates: 0,
              proteins: 0,
              lipids: 0,
              fibers: 0),
          growable: true));
```

As you can see by adding 'Cheesecake' as the name.

In Init functions I just tried this:

```
print(recipes[0][0].name);
```

This work as expected, I accessed the value correctly...

Console Output:

```
Restarted application in 262ms.
flutter: Cheesecake
```

Really don't know why when I arrive at this point:

```
print(recipes[0][0].
```

Visual Studio Code does not show Class/Ingredient properties*, however it works!

*It shows only:

```
hashCode, runtimeType, toString(), noSuchMethod(...)
```

Really hope someone should explain why...

Comment: Your call to `print(recipes[0][0])` is going to invoke the `toString()` method on your `Ingredient` class. You can override this method to print all of the information you'd like to show in the console. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64836405/563509 .

Answer (score 0):

Yup, another practical way to have 2d/3d list:

eg a 3d example:

```
  List<List<List<Ingredient>>> ingredient =
      List.generate(999, (index) => [[]], growable: true);
```

On Init function:

```
ingredient[0][0].clear();
ingredient[0][0].add(Ingredient(
    name: 'Panettone', carboidrates: 0, proteins: 0, lipids: 0, fibers: 0));
print(ingredient[0][0][0].name);
```

And now when I arrive here:

```
print(ingredient[0][0][0].
```

I finally should see the Ingredient Class properties (like name, carboidrates... and so on!)... WIN!