# Firebase Search Field with a Provider as suggestions

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chat

Hello I am making a chat app in flutter with Firebase where you can search users by their username. I builded a Listview of all the users of my application with a

```
Provider.of<List<AppUserData>>(context)
```

for testing and it worked. Now I am trying to use this Stream Provider to provide users by their usernames in a searchbar with the package: searchfield.

[image]

Here's my code :
**search_bar.dart**

```
class SearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchBar> createState() => _SearchBarState();
}

class _SearchBarState extends State<SearchBar> {
  static GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final users = Provider.of<List<AppUserData>>(context);
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: SearchField(
          suggestions: users
              .map((e) =>
                  SearchFieldListItem(e.toString(), child: Text(e.toString())))
              .toList(),
          controller: searchController,
          searchStyle: const TextStyle(color: dLightGrey),
          searchInputDecoration: const InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: dDarkGrey,
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              SocketIconv2.ic_search,
              color: dLightGrey,
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: dLightGrey,
                fontFamily: 'SegoeUI',
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            hintText: 'Search',
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

**database.dart**

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String? uid;

  DatabaseService({this.uid});
  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

  Future<void> saveUser(String name, String username) async {
    return await userCollection
        .doc(uid)
        .set({'name': name, 'username': username});
  }

  AppUserData _userFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return AppUserData(
        name: snapshot['name'], uid: uid, username: snapshot['username']);
  }

  Stream<AppUserData> get user {
    return userCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userFromSnapshot);
  }

  List<AppUserData> _userListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return _userFromSnapshot(doc);
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<AppUserData>> get users {
    return userCollection.snapshots().map(_userListFromSnapshot);
  }

  getUserByUsername(String searchField) async {
    return await userCollection
        .where("username", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchField)
        .get();
  }
}
```

**The parent widget of the search bar :**

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final AuthentificationService _auth = AuthentificationService();
  String myName = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return StreamProvider<List<AppUserData>>.value(
        initialData: [],
        value: DatabaseService().users,
        child: Scaffold(
```

(Everything else is UI)

And finally here's **user.dart**:

```
class AppUser {
  final String? uid;
  AppUser({this.uid});
}

class AppUserData {
  final String? uid;
  final String name;
  final String username;

  AppUserData({this.uid, required this.name, required this.username});
}
```

With my actual Code I got the Text: "Instance of 'AppUserData' instead of the username I asked for.
Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You render `e.toString()` in this code:

```
child: SearchField(
    suggestions: users
        .map((e) =>
            SearchFieldListItem(e.toString(), child: Text(e.toString())))
        .toList(),
```

Since you don't override `toString` in your `AppUser` class, you get the default implementation, which indeed returns the class name.

If you want to show the user's name, either render `e.name` or override `toString` in `AppUser` to return the string you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help but how can I override toString in AppUser ?

Comment: Search is your friend here Ghali: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+can+I+implement+tostring+in+my+own+class+in+flutter. When I recently needed the exact same thing, I thought this top answer was the most helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64836203/what-does-override-tostring-method-do-in-a-flutter-dart-class